# Anyone know how to change greyed out URLs on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, web, url

[Greyed out URLs on WordPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG5A0.jpg)

We have found similar thread about this issue here on SO but we're not coders or programmers so if anyone could explain step-by-step in idiot-proof layman's terms how to edit these greyed out URLs, it would be super appreciated - thanks! (picture in link)

Comment: StackOverflow is a site *for* programmers, so you may find more constructive and appropriate support for yourselves on a different site or forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to change the greyed out URL.
Here I have shared all 3 methods for the same.

**1) Change WordPress Site URLs from Admin Area**

This is the easiest method to change the greyed out URL.

Simply login to your WordPress website and go to **Settings** » **General** page. From here you can change WordPress site URLs under the ‘**WordPress Address**’ and ‘**Site Address**’ options.

[image]

**2) Change WordPress Site URLs Using functions.php File**

Please follow below path and open functions.php file
go to /wp-content/themes/your-theme-folder/.

Next, you need to add the following code at the bottom:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );
```

**3) Change WordPress Site URLs Using wp-config.php File**

Simply open **wp-config.php** file from your **root directory**
You need to add the following code just above the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy publishing’.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
```

Also, you do with the database but I am not recommended.